# Retirar Sábados e Domingos do Cálculo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, datetime

Tenho um projeto em que trabalho com atividades de um projeto, minhas atividades possui um determinado tempo para serem concluídas, porém o projeto tem que fazer o cálculo somente com dias administrativos.

Por exemplo uma atividade começa no dia 26/10/2015 (segunda) e sua duração possui 7 dias ele teria que fazer o calculo e me retornar que o fim da atividade seria no dia  03/11/2015 (seg, ter, quar, qui, sex, seg e ter) teria que remover os sábados e domingos.

Meu projeto está desse jeito:

```
atividade.Inicio = status.InicioPrevisto.Value;
atividade.Duracao = 7;
atividade.Termino = atividade.Inicio.AddDays(duracao);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Achei uma [função pronta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044821/221800) que parece resolver o que deseja.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main()   {
        WriteLine(AddBusinessDays(DateTime.Now, 8));
        WriteLine(AddBusinessDays(new DateTime(2015, 10, 26), 15));
    }

    public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int days) {
        if (days < 0) throw new ArgumentException("days cannot be negative", "days");
        if (days == 0) return date;
        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) {
            date = date.AddDays(2);
            days -= 1;
        } else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
            days -= 1;
        }
        date = date.AddDays(days / 5 * 7);
        int extraDays = days % 5;
        if ((int)date.DayOfWeek + extraDays > 5) extraDays += 2;
        return date.AddDays(extraDays);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hoEG7g). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrPVD5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Hollydays.cs).

Note que os feriados não são considerados. Mas é possível adaptar para que sejam. Não é algo tão simples por causa dos feriados móveis e regionais. Mas é factível se estabelecer bem as regras.

Answer (score 5):

Existe [o pacote NuGet FluentDateTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentDateTime/) que faz isso com muita elegância:

```
atividade.Inicio = status.InicioPrevisto.Value;
atividade.Duracao = 7;
atividade.Termino = atividade.Inicio.AddBusinessDays(duracao);
```

`AddBusinessDays`, assim como `AddDays`, aceita valores positivos e negativos.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, use a Classe GregorianCalendar, veja o exemplo.

```
public Boolean Verificadias()
        {
            // Pega o index do dia da semana...
            int IndexDia = (int)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);
            if (IndexDia > 0 && IndexDia < 6) /// Segunda = 1 a sexta = 5.
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Monte um loop que conte os dias e adicione na sua data..

[link aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx)